# Filter SQL database query by timestamp, backend in PHP using Laravel

Tags: php, sql-server, database, laravel, timestamp

So I'm trying to build a query to my SQL database from my backend (that's written in php with Laravel). I have a table in my database with a column that's titled "created_at", carrying values of the 'timestamp'-type. What I want to do is, when I send a query to my database, to only pick the rows (or instances, I guess) of my table that are created 30 days or less from the current date. I've tried experimenting back and forth with the 'where' keyword, but I couldn't get it to work as I wanted it to.

When I browse the table in my database, the dates are written in the format "YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss" but I'm not sure how to compare them when they're in this format, and I don't know how to convert them whilst doing a query. I've looked at the whereBetween() method in Laravel but I didn't get that to work since I didn't know how I would compare them.

At the moment my query looks like this:

```
$topUser = DB::table('statistics')
            ->join('users', 'statistics.user_id', '=', 'users.id', 'inner')
            ->select('fname', 'user_id', DB::raw('sum(price) as total_collection'))
            ->groupBy('user_id')
            ->orderBy('total_collection','desc')
            ->get();
```

What I want to do, in pseudocode, is something along the lines of;

```
->where 'created_at' <= 30 days ago
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `WHERE("created_at", "<=", DB::raw("NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY"))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's basically that simple.

```
->whereDate('created_at', '<=', \Carbon\Carbon::now()->subDays(30));
```

Comment: Haven't used Carbon, that's some plugin that needs downloading and whatnot, right? Thanks a lot for the answer!

Comment: @NyfikenGul Carbon comes with Laravel by default. Laravel uses it for a lot of date logic internally.

Comment: Ah, I see! That's great, will look into it then

Comment: I get an Integrity Constraint Violation there as well - could it be something else that needed fixing aswell.. ? It says "column 'created_in' where clause is ambiguous..."

Comment: @NyfikenGul That's because of your join. More than one of the joined tables has a `created_at` column. Try `users.created_at` instead of `created_at`.

Comment: Oh, of course! Thank you so much for your answer, seems to be working just fine now!

Answer (score 1):

You can take advantage of mysql's date functions by using `DB::raw`

```
->where('created_at', '<=', DB::raw("DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 30 DAY)")
```

Comment: Best to avoid `DB::raw` if possible. It tends to lock your code down to a single database engine.

Comment: Will try! Thanks chap!

Comment: @ceejayoz You could use `DB::raw` and be SQL compliant at the same time (this query is not though).

Comment: Now I get an Integrity Constant Violation (I basically just pasted that into my code, was there something else that needed adding? Hehe)

Comment: @ceejayoz I've only ever worked with mysql, so I hadn't even thought of that. I'll keep that in mind.